How to do bulk import .csv to Portfolio in Google Finance?
Google Finance has a nice and free of charge Portfolio monitoring tool https://www.google.com/finance/portfolio
How to do bulk import of my operations instead of clicking '+ Investment' hundred times?
I have them in Google Spreadsheets.

Tried asking Google Finance support and/or user community?

@keshlam yes, it did not help for now https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/136576884/how-can-i-import-my-stock-transactions-say-in-excel-and-build-a-portfolio-in-google-finance?hl=en
